# Apply function to clasiffy R

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a table with ids numbers and age:

This is part of the table:

```
View(clasificador1) 
    edad    median  count   
1   21  37758012    1   
2   22  36505316    1   
3   23  36395050    3   
4   24  35430589    3   
5   25  34419796    14  
6   26  33903223    24
```

I want to classify another table using median field. The minimun distance in ids numbers would bring me the age:

```
clasifico_edad<-function(tabla,casificador,dni){
   ff<-function(dni){distances <- abs(dni - clasificador1$median)
                 clasificador1$edad[which.min(distances)]}
   tabla$edad_approx_median <- sapply(tabla[,dni], ff)
   return(tabla)}
```

I filter the letters in the Number field in the table I want to classify:

```
ventas1<-ventas[!grepl("[A-Za-z]", ventas$Number), ]
```

And apply the function:

```
aaaaa<-clasifico_edad(ventas1,clasificador1,"Number")
```

It runs but I get in field edad_approx_median =integer(0) in all rows:

Don't know how to solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you also provide whatever `ventas` is?  Otherwise this isn't reproducible.

Comment: For one, at least this line is not going to work `distances <- abs(dni - clasificador1$median)` since `dni` is a string, which means that your `sapply(tabla[,dni], ff)` is not going to work (which is why you are getting your error). You can try `eval(as.name("dni")` in your `ff` function. I was bogged down by your function definitions so much that I still have 0 idea what you are trying to do here. If you can provide the desired output, I'm there are easier ways than nested function definitions.